# Is there any way to copy SQL with syntax coloring in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to copy some SQL to send in an email, but when I press `Ctrl + C` in pgAdmin 4 and I paste it on any other editor, I get the code in plain text, so no syntax coloring.

Is there any way to copy SQL code from pgAdmin 4 with syntax highlighting?

Comment: Why don't you simply enable syntax highlighting in the "other editor"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The other editor is Gmail. When I copy and paste code from VS Code, Gmail respect the highlighting, but with pgAdming, it doesn't.